# MYSQL Select row_number() doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get row 5 to 10 when sorting by date but for some reason I always end up with this sql error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(ORDER BY CreatedDate) AS Row, GameID, UserID, Title,
>   Description, CreatedDate F' at line 1

This is the query I'm trying to use:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CreatedDate) AS Row, GameID, UserID, Title, Description, CreatedDate
FROM game
WHERE Row >= 5 AND Row <= 10
```

Does someone know what I'm exactly doing wrong here? Or even a better way to solve this problem?

Thanks for reading/helping

Comment: mysql does not have row_number aggregate function. you can use mysql variables for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a rownumber() function in MySQL. This is the closest you can get:

```
SELECT 
    @i:=@i+1 AS rank, 
    t.*
FROM 
    tblname AS t,
    (SELECT @i:=0) AS R
```

Comment: this seems to work but when I try WHERE rank = 1 it ends up crashing again